# Training a model with metadata instead of images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to do a Multi-layer perceptron that has only Metadata(age, gender) as input. After some research, I've decided on a single Fully Connected layer with 500 neurons followed by a softmax layer of size 8(there are 8 categories).

I've arranged my metadata in arrays using one hot encoding. One array is of size 6. The first two columns are related to gender and the other 4 to age. Here is an example:

```
Metadata_Array=
[[0  1  0  0  1  0 ],   #female, age 15
 [1  0  0  0  0  1 ],   #male, age 20
 [0  1  1  0  0  0]]    #female, age 5
```

This is my code:

```
#creating the metadata model
model= Sequential()
model.add(FClayer(neurons=500, activation="linear"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8, activation="softmax")))
```

How can I train my model using only the metadata_array, that is, with no images?
If I were to use images I could use `fit`, but how does it work with non-image "fits"?

Answer (score 1):

`fit()` is a generic method that you'll find in most machine learning libraries (Keras/Tensorflow, scikit-learn, etc).  It means to train your model, and it isn't dependent on the input data being images.  The name comes from "fitting" the output of the model to match the target (if you picture the output of the model being a simple graph of X and Y coordinates, you're fitting the curve to match the data).

You're misusing one hot encoding though.  In one hot encoding, only a single element can be non-zero.  Which element is non-zero tells you which category a sample belongs to.  So for example, you have eight categories you said, which means you want an 8-element array, not a 6-element array.

Just to illustrate, let's one hot encode the days of the week (Mon, Tue, Wed, etc.):

```py
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] == monday
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] == tuesday
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] == wednesday
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] == thursday
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] == friday
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] == saturday
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] == sunday
```

Now let's say you want to *also* track the hour of the day, not just the day of the week: then you'd need 24 elements per day (one per hour), times 7 days per week.  Every hour of every day would be its own category.

So the way you're trying to encode "female, age 15" and "female, age 5" isn't going to work.  You need a single category for each of those, plus a category for all the other possible ages (note that there are better ways of setting up the problem than that, though).

Comment: @mmrion but my categories are types of cancer, like category 1 is skin cancer, category 2 is breast, etc, I just want to see if just by using the metadata how well can it predict. Later I will fuse this with images but that is non-important for now.

Comment: See, the problem is that the loss function you're going to use *depends* on one hot encoding being formatted the way it is in my example.  The short answer is that the math just won't work otherwise.  You can use a different loss, and/or set up your problem differently, but the way you're trying to design it won't work unless you write your own loss function.

Comment: Maybe the naming 'one_hot_encoding' is not correct, but I don't see an issue doing that and calling it encoding with dummy variables.